# React-Bootstrap Form.Label opens file explorer when clicked on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Good afternoon, hopefully everyone is doing fine. My application has a couple of forms that show up in popup modals.

I'm using [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/) for just about everything and I just realized today that every time you click on a <Form.Label> that my "Windows File Explorer" opens up as if I was trying to INPUT a file. Obviously I am NOT trying to input a file, here's an example of my code:

```
<Form.Group controlId="formCreate">
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <Form.Label>Enter a Description</Form.Label>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <Form.Control type="text" className="description" placeholder="Enter a Description (Optional)" />
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Form.Group>
```

As you can see here, it's a simple form group, on my application if I actually CLICK "Enter a Description" the file explorer pops up. I'm confused how that's a thing, considering it's NOT a:

```
<Form.File
   className="position-relative"
   required
   name="file"
   label="File"
   onChange={handleChange}
   isInvalid={!!errors.file}
   feedback={errors.file}
   id="validationFormik107"
   feedbackTooltip
/>
```

Has anyone seen this bug before? It happens for literally every <Form.Label> on my entire application and while it's not the end of the world (the user isn't clicking the label consistently), it is a bug and is annoying. I would appreciate any guidance with this issue.

Here is my package information:

```
"react-bootstrap": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-bootstrap/-/react-bootstrap-1.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-Ep6ZNH6wL5m9bytOS6T9mjSz0YE1bEkc+uHItvenRcA3amr5ApkpKYzAWgdglhRPZHPvm+pnqs1z5IPwv/2UZw==",
  "requires": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.2",
    "@restart/context": "^2.1.4",
    "@restart/hooks": "^0.3.21",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "dom-helpers": "^5.1.2",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "prop-types-extra": "^1.1.0",
    "react-overlays": "^3.0.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.0.0",
    "uncontrollable": "^7.0.0",
    "warning": "^4.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like an element id collision. Inspect the label element in your browser and copy its `for` attribute. Does `window[for]` refer to the element you expect or does it refer to a file input element?

Answer (score 0):

know am a late to this.
Replace your code with the below.

```
<Form.File
 className="position-relative"
 required
 name="file"
 label="File"
 onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} <------make note of the change//
 isInvalid={!!errors.file}
 feedback={errors.file}
 id="validationFormik107"
 feedbackTooltip
/>
```